# cx_Oracle not working on Android

Tags: android, python, oracle, kivy, cx-oracle

I have big problem. I wrote python code with Kivy for Android. I connect Oracle database and take data for my table. Program work in windows but not working on Android Phone. I did the application in Virtual Box using Buildozer. When I read the logcat, problem says:

```
    python  :  ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

Thank you for answers...

Answer (score 0):

did you add cx_oracle to the requirements in the buildozer.spec file?

Comment: No, I didn't. How can I add. In my buildozer.spec wrote requirements=docutils,kivy==master

Comment: just add it to the end of the line like this docutils,kivy==master,cx_oracle

Comment: I tried but my buildozer give this error: # Command failed: pip install --target=/home/kivy/Desktop/myproject/.buildozer/applibs cx_Oracle
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command